# Problem involving cubic field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $L$ be a cubic extension.  I want to show that there exists an element $a \in F,$ and an extension $L_0$ of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ such that

$-[L_0:\mathbb{Q}(a)]=3$

$-L=FL_0$ (the composite)

I think I have a solution if I assume that $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q},$ but not in general. I would appreciate some guidance.

Solution (sketch) if F algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}:$ pick any element $b \in L$ with $b \notin F$ and note by degree considerations that $L=F(b).$  Let $a_1, a_2, a_3$ be the coefficients of the minimal polynomial $b$ over $F.$

Now let $L_0:=\mathbb{Q}(a_1, a_2,a_3).$ By the primitive element theorem, there exists $a\in F$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(a_1, a_2,a_3)=\mathbb{Q}(a).$  The minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is the same as over $L_0$ so we have $[L_0:\mathbb{Q}(a)]=3,$ and it is easy to check that $L=FL_0.$

Comment: In characteristic $0$, any finite extension is separable and any finite separable extension is simple.

Comment: I knew that, but I fail to see how it solves the problem unfortunately. Could you give a little more detail?

Comment: Your proof in the algebraic case looks right to me, but I’m not at all sure that the statement is true in the general case. Do you have reason to think that it is?

Comment: This question is taken from the fall 2008 UCLA algebra qualifying exam, but I guess it's possible that the examiners goofed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place that you use the fact that $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ is in the primitive element theorem. If for some reason your irreducible polynomial will have only one parameter (instead of three), then your solution will still work.

Suppose that your polynomial is $f(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C$. First consider the polynomial $g(x)=f(x-\frac{A}{3})=x^3+B'x+C'$, which defines the same extension over $F$, but has only two parameters. If $C'=0$ or $B'=0$, then you are done. Otherwise define $h(x)=(\frac{B'}{C'})^3g(\frac{C'}{B'}x)=x^3+\frac{B'^3}{C'^2}(x+1)$. Now the polynomial has only one parameter which is $\frac{B'^3}{C'^2}$. This is basically the "completing the square" trick, only in degree 3.